# C++: Reverse sort pair with custom value inside it

Tags: c++, stl

After searching on google for some time I was not able to find a answer specifically answering this question. How to reverse sort a c++ STL pair with some custom type in it

```
pair <long long, pair< int, int > > p[MAX];
```

Comment: @frerich-raabe No. Thats vector of pair with standard c++ data types and in my question its array of pairs with(can be customized) custom types in it.

Comment: If you compare the answers, you'll see that the types of the two fields of the `std::pair` values don't matter. The solution is always some sort of comparison function which checks one (or both) of the fields. I don't think it's helpful to create new questions for any plausible configuration of std::pair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

const int MAX = 1e5 + 5;
typedif pair <long long, pair< int, int > > pll;
pll p[MAX];

//custom sort function can be customized
bool SortByWeight(pll x, pll y){ 
    return x.first > y.first;
}

int main(){
    //enter size
    cin>>szie;
    //Ex: p = [(10101, (2,3)), (129334, (4, 7))....]
    sort(p, p+size, SortByWeight)
}
```

Custom function can be customized for custom type. For ex for class we can use use class_obj.variable_name etc

- Source My blog [mypynotes](https://mypynotes.wordpress.com/2015/07/29/c-reverse-sort-pair-with-custom-value-inside-it/).

Answer (score 0):

`std::pair` provides a member-wise `operator <` on its own (as well as `operator >`), so all you need to do is ask `std::sort` to use `operator >`:

```
std::sort(p, p + MAX, std::greater<pair <long long, pair< int, int > >>());
```

More documentation here: [std::pair](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair), [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), [std::greater](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater).

Comment: You can even use `std::greater<>()` :)